# Pastespecial method of range class failed - Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, error-handling, copy-paste

I need you help. I really do not understand what is the wrong with my code. I always get an error message at this point:

```
Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

The error message is that: **Pastespecial method of range class failed**

What I want is to filter the raw data and copy the result to a new sheet in the workbook.

Do you have any suggestion what is the problem with my code?
Thank you for your help in advance!

```
 Sub copypaste()

    Dim i, j, v As Long
    Dim vSearchCols As Variant
    Dim vCols As Variant
    Dim FilterFor As String

    FilterFor = "=AF*"
    Set s1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RAW DATA")
    Set s2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("AF SITE TYPE")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False


    With s1
        vSearchCols = Array("Prefix+short name", "Site type", "Probe Id", "Owner", "SLA Target", "Avg RTT (ms)", "Completion (ms)")
        ReDim vCols(0 To UBound(vSearchCols))
            For v = LBound(vSearchCols) To UBound(vSearchCols)
                vCols(v) = .rows(2).Cells.Find(What:=vSearchCols(v), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole).Column
            Next v
    End With

    With s1
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
        With .Cells.Resize(.rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0)
        If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Cells)) Then
            .AutoFilter Field:=vCols(0), Criteria1:=FilterFor
            .Copy
            Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            ActiveSheet.Name = "TEMP"
        End If
        End With
    End With

    End Sub
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to copy the sheet, then just delete what you don't need?

Comment: Adding the sheet clears the clipboard. You should add it, then copy and paste.

Comment: I have already tried to add a new sheet first and then copy, but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: what happens if you change `.Copy` to `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy`.  And while you are at it, change `Sheets.Add` to `ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add` (and separate out the add and the paste calls).

Comment: What code did you try exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
ws.Name = "TEMP"
With s1
    If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
    With .Cells.Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0)
    If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Cells)) Then
        .AutoFilter Field:=vCols(0), Criteria1:=FilterFor
        .Copy
        ws.Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    End If
    End With
End With
```

Or some completely revised code:

```
Sub copypaste()

    Dim i, j, v               As Long
    Dim vSearchCols           As Variant
    Dim vCols                 As Variant
    Dim FilterFor             As String
    Dim ws                    As Worksheet
    Dim s1                    As Worksheet
    Dim s2                    As Worksheet


    FilterFor = "=AF*"
    With ThisWorkbook
        Set s1 = .Worksheets("RAW DATA")
        Set s2 = .Worksheets("AF SITE TYPE")
        Set ws = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
    End With
    ws.Name = "TEMP"

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    vSearchCols = Array("Prefix+short name", "Site type", "Probe Id", "Owner", "SLA Target", "Avg RTT (ms)", "Completion (ms)")
    ReDim vCols(0 To UBound(vSearchCols))
    For v = LBound(vSearchCols) To UBound(vSearchCols)
        vCols(v) = s1.Rows(2).Cells.Find(What:=vSearchCols(v), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole).Column
    Next v

    With s1
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        With .Range("A1").CurrentRegion
            .AutoFilter Field:=vCols(0), Criteria1:=FilterFor
            If .Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count > 1 Then
                .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
                ws.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            End If
        End With
    End With
    With Application
        .DisplayAlerts = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hmmm it is still not working. Maybe something is wrong with raw data? Raw data is just number and string, that is it :/

Comment: Do you have any merged cells in the source data?

Comment: The first row is merged but that is why I am using this in the code: `With .Cells.Resize(.rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0)`

Comment: Does it work if you replace (just to test) the two copy/paste special lines with just this: `.Copy Destination:=ws.Cells(1, 1)`

Comment: in this case the error message is: **Copy method of range class failed**

Comment: And if you use two lines: `.Copy` followed by `ws.Paste`?

Comment: Still getting error: **Method Paste of object _Worksheet failed**

Comment: Can you put a sample file somewhere (Onedrive / Dropbox etc) and post a link here so I can see what's happening?

Comment: The revised code I posted works fine for me with that workbook.

Comment: Yes, revised code is working. Can you please tell me what caused the issue? What was wrong with my code? Thanks

Comment: Mostly the fact that you were copying almost all the cells on the sheet, which caused a memory issue I think.